# Silverlight not searching for ClientAccessPolicy.xml

Tags: silverlight, websocket, websocket4net

I'm working with Silverlight and WebSocket4Net and get an error when attempting to connect.  The problem is with the underlying socket:

{System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.}

There is no InnerException or StackTrace below this.

It does not try to find the ClientAccessPolicy.xml -- at all.

I'm trying to connect to another computer, say 10.0.0.102, and that I'm from 10.0.0.101.  I can access 10.0.0.102/ClientAccessPolicy.xml just fine.  However, in Fiddler, it doesn't even attempt to load 10.0.0.102/ClientAccessPolicy -- no call is made to find it.

Because of this, my attempt to call and connect to the WebSocket via TCP doesn't work at all (i.e. ws://10.0.0.102:4530/WebSockOutput/).  I've manually set the Socket's ClientAccessPolicyProtocol to Http...  When I check at the lower layers, it's still setting the CAPP correctly.

Any thoughts?

I'd also like to add that I've rebooted and cleared the Temp directory on both machines **several** times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem is REALLY REALLY REALLY **sad**, on my part.

Apparently it already cached the ClientAccessPolicy.xml (which I'd changed to support the TCP Ports), and though I thought I was killing the temporary internet files, I wasn't.  I deleted my history/downloaded data from IE's Options, and that fixed everything.

One would think that Silverlight would attempt to re-download the ClientAccessPolicy a bit more frequently...